# A boat is traveling at 30 knots/hour at 30 degrees E of N. Find the components of the velocity vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Would it be 15 knots per hour or like 15$\sqrt{3}$ knots??

I'm not sure if I understand this please help.

Comment: Do you how to find the components of a vector when given an angle?

Comment: Knots per hour? Is that acceleration or speed?

Comment: I think I do, the question says knots per hour

Comment: Then the question is wrong: knots is a unit of speed. 30 knots means 30 nautical miles per hour.

Comment: I'm not sure but that's what my prof put, maybe it's just generic or for the purpose of the question.

Comment: It's an easy mistake to make. I wouldn't worry about it if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

Its nothing more than that of $30\cos(30)j=30.\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}j=15\sqrt{3}j$ and $30\sin(30)i=30.\frac{1}{2}i=15i$ where $i,j$ are unit vectors.i is unit vector in $X$ direction and j in $Y$ direction

Comment: So it is 15sqrt(3) ?

Comment: Oh so it's like  [  15   15sqrt(3)  ]  right , where i=15 is on top and j=15sqrt3 on bottom ?

Comment: I have edited see everything always has two vector components cos and sin

Comment: I just got confused when it says East of North

Comment: Its just 30 from north

Comment: wait so So X direction is 15 and Y direction is 15sqrt(3)  correct?  It's all together so I'm not sure because you put a period in between those? and the i's and j's basically cancel out ?

Comment: Lol no they represent x,y axis you better learn finding components or its useless to explain